# Spacemacs yellow line

Tags: highlight, spacemacs, yellow

I am a novice when use Spacemacs. when edit c++ files. there are yellow highlight lines. so I want to disable the yellow highlight and what does the yellow hightlight means?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The yellow highlights are whitespace. If you do not want whitespace to show you can add `(setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)` to the `dotspacemacs/user-config` section in your `.spacemacs` (open with `SPC f e d` and reload with `SPC f e R`).

I prefer to keep the whitespace highlighting enabled and remove trailing whitespace automatically. This can be done by changing the variable `dotspacemacs-whitespace-cleanup` in `dotspacemacs/init` to `'all`, `'trailing` or `'changed`.